# The on-click event function is not working on Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, onclick

Im fairly new to Vue framework, when I try to implement onclick event handler function it seems not to work.

Here is the code below:

Template:

```
<template>
            </div>
            <div class = "btn-field">
                <button type ="button" id="signup">Sign up</button>
                <button type ="button" id="signin" class= "disable">Sign in</button>
                </div>

</template>
```

Style:

```
<style>

.btn-field button{ 
    color: #3c00a0;
    transition: background 1s;
}



.btn-field button.disable{
    background: #eaeaea;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}



</style>
```

Script:

`<script>`

`let signup = document.getElementById("signup");`

`let signin = document.getElementById("signin");`

`let name = document.getElementById("name");`

`let title = document.getElementById("title");`

`signin.onclick = function(){`

`nameField.style.maxHeight = "0";`

`title.innerHTML = "Sign In";`

`signup.classList.add("disable");`

`signin.classList.remove("disable");`

`}`

`</script>`

Comment: You shouldn't access DOM directly in the first place without a good reason in Vue. Check the guide regarding the way it's supposed to be done, it covers click events and class handling